# Sabre - PNR Baggagefees, Endorsement information

Tags: sabre

We're using TravelItineraryReadRS to retrieve PNR details and the baggagefees, Endorsement information seems to only exisit in the Price Quote section.

```
-<ItineraryInfo>
  -<ItineraryPricing>
    -<PriceQuote RPH="1">
     -<MiscInformation>
       -<BaggageFees>
```

The problem is there might be multiple Price Quote sections for each PNR. Is there a separte API that will return the final details for the PNR?

Comment: Those *are* the final details. There *are* multiple PQ sections, one per segment if I remember correctly. Did you check the documentation in Dev Studio?

Comment: You will have as many PQ as you saved when pricing. You could have none, or you could have many, all of which will be returned by TravelItineraryReadRQ.

Comment: We notice that there counld be multiple PQs in TravelItineraryReadRQ and the data change depends on the pricing. Where/How we can retrieve the final details for  baggagefees, Endorsement infomration.